# Why TestNG's beforeSuite only provides a value for one class while the other class gets null?

Tags: java, testng

I have a problem with the `BeforeSuite` annotation in TestNG.
I want to initialize some variables in `beforeSuite()` so all the classes could use them directly. Only class A can get the value. Class B can't; it gets null.

Base.java:

```
public class Base {
    public String name;
    @BeforeSuite
    public void beforeSuite(){
        name = "stackoverflow";
    }
}
```

A.java:

```
public class A extends Base{
    @Test
    public void test(){
        System.out.println("A name:" + name);
    }

}
```

B.java

```
public class B extends Base{
    @Test
    public void test(){
        System.out.println("B name:" + name);
    }

}
```

textng.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="suite1" parallel="classes" thread-count="1" preserve-order="true">
   <test name="testValue">
        <classes>
            <class name="A"/>
            <class name="B"/>
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

test result:

```
mvn clean test
.
.
.
[INFO] Running TestSuite
B name:null
A name:stackoverflow
```

My TestNG version is 6.8.8.

Comment: I hope this [Link](https://github.com/cbeust/testng/issues/2158) can give you an idea why its not working. If you are looking for alternative make it `@BeforeClass` instead of `@BeforeSuite`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies in the test code. You have a common base class that is being extended by multiple child classes and within the base class you have a `@BeforeSuite` method.

TestNG by behavior, guarantees that the `@BeforeSuite` method gets executed ONLY once per `<suite>` tag.

In your case, it already got invoked for class `A` and so it will be skipped for class `B` which explains the `NullPointerException`.

To fix this, you would need to move your initialization to either a `@BeforeMethod` or `@BeforeClass` annotated method.

Answer (score 0):

If the use case is to set a variable at the suite setup time in base class which should be available to all sub classes, you can make that static in base class.